# Setting Username and Password in commandline for TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I want to set Username and password for TortiseSVN while performing

TortoiseProc.exe /command:export /path:"https://collaborate.bt.com/svn/sandbox/branches\" /url:"c:\Tempo123\" /notempfile /closeonend:1

Pls help me out

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [you cannot with TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#username).

If you want to use svn non-interactively, use the svn.exe command line client. You can download it from e.g. http://subversion.tigris.org/getting.html#windows

Comment: But there must be sum way out i can use SVN with tortiseSVN sumway..
And also the SVN u mentioned is it this one

CollabNet Subversion Server and Client v1.6.6 (for Windows)